# Full Swing / Go With A Swing

Tags: idioms

In what context do we usually use 'Go With A Swing /Full Swing'?

Can I use it when I'm having a casual conversation with my family and friends?

Comment: I've never even *heard* of either of those—so I don't know what they mean. Taking a wild guess, I'd say they sound something like *go for broke* or *the full monty*. But I'd really need to see them used in the context of an actual sentence to be more confident about that. And I'm not sure what you mean by "can" you use them in casual conversation. Assuming they had meaning to everybody involved, then why couldn't you?

Comment: Music is a possible context, as in play with a swing. Maybe walk with a swing (of the hips or the arms). Maybe the sentence could be used when advising somebody what playground equipment to buy.

Comment: The first means that something works or is happening very well, effortlessly. The second used in the context "the party was in full swing" means it had already started and people were enjoying themselves. The first isn't "usually used in conversation", I think it is rather dated now. The second can still be heard.

Comment: This is a golf analogy, I think, where a full swing puts everything you’ve got onto the ball. It’s okay with family but won’t mean much if golf terminology is unfamiliar.

Comment: See https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6BdUMJsn8oQ

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-with-a-swing  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-full-swing  I doubt it's anything to do with golf.

Comment: I'd say they're rather dated nowadays; the Swing Era was the 1920s and 30s, and whatever the etymology of the expressions, this surely has always informed their connotations. _It don't mean a thing if it ain't got swing._ They're also less (!?) than formal, and would not be out of place in informal contexts. But there are more modern idioms, I'm almost sure.

Comment: @Weather Vane OP confusingly gives both orders. I didn't see your 'dated'; glad we agree, at least in part, and certainly 'go with a swing' invokes past times. These things are hard to substantiate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth perhaps they have different derivations, the first from a music genre, the second (as Xanne says) from golf. When the golf club is 'in full swing' there is no stopping it. It has momentum.

Comment: @Weather Vane I'd say they must have the same origin, but after that, etymological strands are as varied as the connotations words and fixed expressions collect and propagate. A multi-braided stream. Some channels doubtless wider than others.

Comment: The expressions "go with a swing" is not idiomatic in U.S. English, but newspaper records indicate that it is (or was) for many decades idiomatic in Australian English and perhaps also in British English. A couple of days ago, I wrote most of aa fairly extensive answer to this question when my computer suddenly crashed and the answer vanished. I may try to rewrite it if the question stays open long enough.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathon Green, *Chambers Dictionary of Slang* (2008) offers this reference to "go with a swing":

> **swing** *n.<sup>2</sup>* {1970s+} *(US black)* stimulation, excitement, something that makes things 'go with a swing'.

However, none of the four Black/African-American slang dictionaries I have on hand, published from 1994 to 2006, mentions "swing" in the sense of stimulation or excitement or the phrase "go with a swing," so Green's entry is something of an outlier on this point.

An Elephind newspaper database search of U.S. and Australian/New Zealand newspapers turns up 1,726 matches for "go with a swing" and one match for "go with a full swing" for the period from 1879 to 1980. The surprising thing here is that 1,626 of the matches are from Australia, 92 are from the United States, and 8 are from New Zealand. It thus appears that if "go with a swing" is an idiomatic expression, it is much more an Australian one than a U.S. one. A sampling of instances over the years suggests that the sense of the phrase remained remarkably consistent over more than 70 years.

From "[The Artillery Band](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/8980013?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+swing%22)," in the *[Hobart, Tasmania] Mercury* (August 9, 1879):

> Mr. Dickens, as Charlie Spraggs, and a lady amateur (whose name was not divulged), as Kitty, a pair of comic lovers, were highly diverting. The numoroua other *roles* were also rendered in a manner that made the comedy **go with a swing** through. The musical and military farce, *Our National Defences*, composed expressly for the occasion, concluded the programme, causing abundant laughter all over the house.

From "[Maitland](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/71017459?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+swing%22)," in the *[New South Wales] Australian Town and Country Journal* (September 20, 1884):

> CO-OPERATION.—The farmers are very busy in the formation of a farmers' co-operative society, and the thing promises to **go with a swing**.

From "[Musical and Literary Entertainment](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/98439087?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+swing%22)," in the *Goulbourn [New South Wales] Evening Penny Post* (July 30, 1885):

> The Rev. Mr. Martin said they had now to revert to the first item of the programme, and that was an address by himself. It would not be a long one. They had seen a specimen, a very good specimen, of the team he had to drive. The young men and young women present could, if they liked, make the society **go with a swing**; and he hoped it would go on and be a success. It was a society for the improvement of their minds, their manners, and their morals.

From "[Irrigation Colonies](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/96940235?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+swing%22)," in the *[Port Elliot, South Australia] Southern Argus* (January 19, 1893):

> What is really needed is a broad and public-spirited feeling and policy on the part of those doing such a work, and such men at its head who will gain the confidence of the public, and especially those who are inclined to invest. Moreover, everything must be well and clearly defined. We do not want a syndicate to advertise one thing and then offer something totally different when personal enquiry is made. The whole thing must be on straight lines, then, and only, then, will it **go with a swing** and prove a real success[.]

From "[Royal Princess's Theatre: 'The Blue Moon'](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/89856246?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+swing%22)," in the *Bendigo [Victoria] Advertiser* (August 20, 1907):

> And fifth, but by no means last, comes the last stranger, Mr. Goariet, as Moohaj—idol-maker, fun-maker, dancer, singer, juggler,  general fool of the play. His "get-up" was splendid, his facial expressions good, and his local hits clever. His every entry presaged fresh fooling and fresh amusement, and it is difficult to say which was the more amusing, he or the Private Taylor. He was full of life and bustle all the time he was on, and was simply immense in "The Crocodile," and caused endless merriment in "Make a Fuss of Me." it was indeed a fine male quintet, and they made everything **go with a swing**, they and that clover fun-maker, Miss Wallace.

From "[Vive La Belgique! Children Assist a Brave Nation: Grand Bazaar at Nhill School](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/129564485?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+swing%22)" in the *Nhill [Victoria] Free Press* (March 30, 1915):

> Than ks to the excellent organisation of Mr. W. D. Thomas, and his staff, the whole proceedings passed off without a hitch. The teachers and children worked harmoniously together—each one, from the tiny dot to the oldest, labored earnestly and energetically to make the bazaar "**go with a swing**," and it is pleasing indeed to learn that their efforts have been crowned with success, and that the Nhill School has put up a record for the State of Victoria in gathering on a single day £105 to assist the poor distressed Belgians.

From "[New Year's Day Sports](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/79635626?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+swing%22)," in the *[Barcaldine, Queensland] Western Champion* (January 1, 1927):

> To-day's (Saturday) effort is undoubtedly going to be a fine one. A great deal of trouble has been taken with the arrangements and right from the start of the proceedings it is anticipated that everything will **go with a swing**, and will equal any sports gathering hitherto held in Barcaldine. The procession will be interesting, and there should be keen competition between those entering decorated vehicles.

From "[Party Games: A Few Suggestions](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/41609305?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+swing%22)," in the *[Perth] West Australian* (January 21, 1938):

> Parties are more frequent at this time of the year, when the kiddies are home from school, than at any other, and hostesses are sometimes in doubt as to how to entertain their guests. Even at family reunions, games and competitions are needed to make the evening **go with a swing**. Here are some novelty games which provide a lot of fun for the players.

From "[Music for Bowlers](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/49366035?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+swing%22)," in the *[Brisbane, Queensland] Courier-Mail* (October 17, 1946):

> Mrs. Morris, the wife of one of the visiting bowlers,has charmed her froends and many local residents with her soprano voice.
>
> Mr. F. Molyneux, organist at St. Andrew's, Newcastle, has given recitals at Stanthorpe, Warwick, Toowoomba, and Brisbane, and Mr. A. Hooker, a commercial traveller, has contributed items on the violin.
>
> The three have combined to make the trip **go with a swing**. Said one member yesterday: "As well as enjoyable bowls matches, we are being charmed by a feast of bright social functions."

And from "[Seen at the Club](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/65171549?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+swing%22)," in the *[Alice Spring, Northern Territory] Centralian Advocate* (March 27, 1953):

> Brightest party of the night, and there were two or three very gay shows, was a birthday party to popular Sister Marge Phillips. Marge was 2i and some months (according to friends present) right on the day. Many more happies to her.
>
> There helping make the party **go with a swing** were Sister Noela Nash (Natch) and Ray Felgate. Tom and Pat Hogan, Ursula Dale, Mill Evans, Kev. Wren and Sister Audrey Frost, John Harris, Capt. Mich Hammett and June Piet, Dr. Roach was there, also Mrs. T. Harris.

It thus appears that in Australia, over a period of at least seven decades, "go with a swing" meant "be a success" or "win popular acclaim."

The phrase seems to have fallen off in popularity in recent decades, however. The numbers of Elephind matches, by decade, is as follows: 1870s, 1 match; 1880s, 5 matches; 1890s, 58 matches; 1900s, 140 matches; 1910s, 265 matches; 1920s, 365 matches; 1930s, 409 matches; 1940s, 262 matches; 1950s, 206 matches; 1960s, 6 matches; 1970s, 15 matches; and 1980s, 3 matches. Although copyright issues may be responsible for a general reduction in searchable newspapers in recent decades, the drop-off between the 1950s and the 1960s is quite sharp.

---

The only Elephind match for "go with a full swing" suggests that this phrase has (or had) a similar idiomatic meaning to "go with a swing." From "[The Smart Set](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/90598138?searchTerm=%22go+with+a+full+swing%22)," in the *Maryborough & Dunolly [Victoria] Advertiser* (February 16, 1914):

> An English newspaper, in writing of this company, says:‚"Something that is neither a concert, a vaudeville performance, nor a musical comedy, and yet partakes of all—such is the definition of the entertainment provided at the Queen's Hall by 'The Smart Set.'Individually the artists are admirably equipped. They are vocalists, one and all; one or two of them are splendid dancers; in quartette singing they would be hard to beat; and in ensemble they move about the stage with an abandon and neatness that makes the show **go with a full swing** from first to last."

The fact that this instance is reproduced from "an English newspaper" suggests that "go with a full swing"—and perhaps also "go with a swing"—
originated in Britain and later migrated to Australia. The Elephind newspaper database doesn't include UK newspapers, but there is at least circumstantial evidence here that the idiom was current in the UK as well as in Australia more than a hundred years ago.

Answer (score 0):

“In full swing” is defined here:

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+full+swing

This includes etymology—supposedly Used about an English barrister about his career being at its peak.

To me it’s a sports analogy (golf).

Comment: Etymon indicates that the literal senses for _swing_ (flog, fling oneself) predate the career etc-related usages, which are thus metaphorical. In later years, surely the Swing Era was both named for the energetic displacements involved and then strongly informed people's perceptions of the word and its expressions.

Comment: I've only heard "in full swing" used of parties -- to indicate that a large number of guests have arrived, and people are chatting and having drinks instead of hanging nervously about..

Comment: The OED has "full swing" from the mid 19th century to mean "at full speed; with the utmost vigour or energy", next to a mid 19th century sense of "swing" meaning "Continuous vigorous movement or progress." Despite what The Free Dictionary says, it seems unlikely that it would be from a 16th century sense of "swing" meaning "period of time" if the phrase only originated 300 years later.